# finding the derivative of a square root function ..

Tags: calculus

[image]

so this problem is really annoying me and i'm not sure if I messed up a sign in the problem or what. But this is the answer I came up with $$y'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Almost correct, but I believe you lost a minus sign while differentiating.

Comment: so would it be 1/2*sqrt((1-x)/(1+x))??@AndreiRykhalski

Comment: This formula is the same as in your original post. Just try to differentiate $y(x)$ again and you will get a correct answer. As mentioned in the first comment, minus sign comes from differentiating $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss a minus sign. When you differentiate $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, it will give you a minus, which can't be cancelled.